# Coarse graining large data set to something that can be plotted on python

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, mean

Let's say I have

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib. pyplot as plt
N_orig = 1000000
x_orig = np.linspace(0,np.pi,N_orig)
y_orig = np.sin(x_orig)

plt.plot(x_orig,y_orig,'*')
plt.show()
```

Okay, any decent machine can run this code, but it's not very practical anyway.

I would like to coarse grain the x-coordinate by doing something like

```
N_new = 100
x_new = np.linspace(0,np.pi,N_new)
dx=abs(x_new[1]-x_new[0])
y_new = ???
```

such that `y_new[i]` is the value of `y_new[i]=np.mean(y_orig[x[i]-dx/2 < x_orig and x_orig < x[i]+dx/2])`

I know that for looping over `i` is a solution, but I want something faster. Is there an available routine?

Comment: Please read again what you wrote (the definition of `y_new`), there seems to be several mistakes...

Comment: @RandomGuy Exactly where?

Answer (score 0):

If your `x` array is in fact `x_new`, then your question is a bit overpowered as you simply want the values of `y_new` to be the means of `y_ori` on intervals of fixed lengths *(except on the sides of your array)*, as `x_ori` and `x_new` discretize the **same interval**, but with different steps.

Thus no need to write something as complicated as `y_orig[x[i]-dx/2 < x_orig and x_orig < x[i]+dx/2]`, you could simply calculate the means of `y_ori` on these intervals. To do so :

```
fixed_len = ((x_new[1]-dx/2 < x_orig) & (x_orig < x_new[1]+dx/2)).sum() # No need to write this, you could calculate it directly with a bit of mathematics. 
# Warning : don't do it on x_new[0] as you'll experience side effect

y_new = y_ori.reshape((-1, fixed_len)) # -1 so that the number of lines is automatically inferred.
y_new = np.mean(y_new, axis=1)
```

The downside of this method is that it does not take care of side effects *(the beginning and end of* `y_new`*, where the length of the array to average is not equal to* `fixed_len`*)*, thus it is not exactly correct. One simple solution would be to compute these means before (that is to say, compute with your formula on `i=0` and `i=-1`), and apply this piece of code to `x_new` without it's extremal values corresponding to `i=0` and `i=-1` in your definition of `y_new`.

You would then only have to concatenate those arrays.